# when invoke AWS lambda from client, in lambda code, how to retrieve CognitoAWSCredentials to access other services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, client-server

I have a feature where lambda function read/write to DynamoDB.
In client, user sign in Cognito and create CognitoAWSCredentials to invoke lambda function.
In lambda code, how to retrieve that CognitoAWSCredentials to access DynamoDB?

if it's not possible to retrieve, which AWSCredentials I can use to access DynamoDB in lambda code?

Comment: Lamba always has an issue role associated, AWS takes care of retrieving credentials for that role, just give that role the necessary permissions and you are good to go.

Comment: thank for your answer, but when you construct a DynamoDbClient to access DynamoDB, you need to provide credentials: public AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWSCredentials credentials), how to get AWSCredentials to provide?

Comment: Don't use that constructor, use the one without credentials or use the default client. Check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two models here:

1. the client itself can use its Cognito credentials to [get AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html) and use those to make DynamoDB API calls directly.
2. the client can make an API request via API Gateway to a Lambda function and that Lambda function uses its own AWS credentials (associated with the Lambda function's [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)) to make DynamoDB API calls.

You seem to be using the latter strategy, so ensure that the permissions associated with your Lambda function's IAM role have the necessary DynamoDB permissions.